# index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1- python

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have used Markov clustering (MCL) to cluster data of (6) points, the input to MCL is a matrix.

**my data:**

```
import warnings
import math
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
import scipy.spatial.distance as distance
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
%matplotlib inline
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import markov_clustering as mc
import networkx as nx
import random

data = np.array([
    [0.13, 0.19, 0.21, 0.13, 0.23, 0.05, 0.05],
    [0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.15, 0.5, 0.05, 0.12],
    [0.12, 0.29, 0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.11, 0.14],
    [0.02, 0.13, 0.18, 0.14, 0.09, 0.05, 0.39],
    [0.49, 0.06, 0.02, 0.13, 0.1, 0.09, 0.11],
    [0.11, 0.18, 0.35, 0.14, 0.09, 0.07, 0.06]])

Matrix =np.array([[0, 0.0784, 0.032768, 0.097216, 0.131008, 0.025792],
       [0.0784  , 0, 0.142144, 0.16768 , 0.223104, 0.174848],
       [0.032768, 0.142144, 0, 0.069312, 0.126656, 0.053056],
       [0.097216, 0.16768 , 0.069312, 0, 0.212224, 0.095232],
       [0.131008, 0.223104, 0.126656, 0.212224, 0, 0.173312],
       [0.025792, 0.174848, 0.053056, 0.095232, 0.173312, 0]])
```

Then I use MCL algorithm on the matrix to return the clusters.

```
def addSelfLoop(Matrix):
    size = len(Matrix)
    for i in range(size):
        Matrix[i][i] = 1
    return Matrix

def createTransition(Matrix):
    size = len(Matrix)
    Transition = [[0 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]
    for j in range(size):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(size):
            sum += Matrix[i][j]
        for i in range(size):
            Transition[i][j] = round(Matrix[i][j]/sum, 2)
    return Transition

def expand(Transition):
    size = len(Transition)
    Expansion = [[0 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            sum = 0
            for k in range(size):
                sum += Transition[i][k] * Transition[k][j]
            Expansion[i][j] = round(sum,2)
    return Expansion

def inflate(Expansion, power):
    size = len(Expansion)
    Inflation = [[0 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            Inflation[i][j] = math.pow(Expansion[i][j],power)

    for j in range(size):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(size):
            sum += Inflation[i][j]
        for i in range(size):
            Inflation[i][j] = round(Inflation[i][j]/sum, 2)
    return Inflation

import math
def change(Matrix1, Matrix2):
    size = len(Matrix1)
    change = 0
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if(math.fabs(Matrix1[i][j]-Matrix2[i][j]) > change):
                change = math.fabs(Matrix1[i][j]-Matrix2[i][j])
    return change

def MCL(Matrix):
    
    Matrix = addSelfLoop(Matrix)
    print (pd.DataFrame(Matrix))
    Gamma = 2
    Transition = createTransition(Matrix)
    M1 = Transition
    print ("Transition")
    print (pd.DataFrame(M1))
    
    counter =1
    epsilon = 0.001
    change_ = float("inf")
    while (change_ > epsilon):
        print("Iterate :: ", counter,":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
        counter += 1
        # M_2 =  M_1 * M_1  #  expansion  
        M2 = expand(M1)
        print ("expanded\n",pd.DataFrame(M2))
        # M_1 =  Γ(M_2)     #  inflation
        M1 = inflate(M2, 2)
        print ("inflated\n",pd.DataFrame(M1))
        # change   =  difference(M_1, M_2)
        change_ = change(M1,M2)
    return M1

result = mc.run_mcl(Matrix, inflation=1.8)
clusters = mc.get_clusters(result)
print('clusters', clusters)
print('No. clusters=', len(clusters))
```

The output of cluster:

```
clusters [(0,), (1, 5), (2,), (3, 4)]
No. clusters= 4
```

Finally, I tried to create labels for data points (6)

the expected output:

```
data point   cluster
0               0
1               1
2               2
3               3
4               3
5               1
```

when I run the following code

```
#Create labels
out_label = np.zeros((Matrix.shape[0],1), dtype=np.int)
for i,data in enumerate(clusters):
    for fine_data in data:
        out_label[data] = i+1
out_label
```

I get the following error:

```
----> 5         out_label[data] = i+1

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In that line, Matrix would need to be an `int`. Did you maybe mean to use `Matrix.shape[0]` in `np.zeros()`?

Comment: I want to create or return the label for each data point (her 6 data point with corresponding label)